# Memory management pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I saw a common practice of deleting the pointer amd making it null in destructor even if no memory is allocated to pointer on heap. Consider below C++ code:

dummy.h

```
class dummy
{
     int* a;
}
```

dummy.cpp

```
  dummy::dummy():a(NULL)
   { cout<<Inside Const"; }

   dummy::~dummy()
  {
    if(a!=NULL)
    {
      delete a;
      a = NULL;
    }
  }

  bool func()
  {
     a = func1();
  }
```

In above code although  memory to a is not allocated on heap, even then it is deleted. It should not lead to memory leak?

Comment: your question is a bit ambiguos ...

Comment: @DavidHaim - What are you finding ambiguous over here?Don't you think your comment is ambiguous ?

Comment: Common practice to make the pointer NULL in the destructor? What for?

Comment: @juanchopanza - Sorry. Didn't got your question.

Comment: @juanchopanza: When debugging, it makes it 100% clear to the debugger(person) that the memory has already been freed.  Many people swear by it.  Many people swear against it.

Comment: Don't do this. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4666535/12711

Comment: Is `func()` being called? What is `a` in it? (Is `func` supposed to be a member of `dummy`?) Where is delete being called with no memory allocated?

Comment: @MooingDuck It would only make it 100% clear that a local pointer has been set to NULL. The memory doesn't even have to be freed for that.

Comment: @juanchopanza: True.  Many people develop the habit that when they free memory, they set it to NULL, in which case, the null-ness of the pointer always reflects the validity of the pointer.  Is it foolproof? No, but no code is.  It's simply a practice that when used properly helps when debugging. That's all.

Comment: @MooingDuck The downside is that it makes it look like they don't know what they are doing.

Comment: @juanchopanza: In your opinion.  In their opinion, leaving it pointing to invalid memory is a novice mistake.  Subjective either way.  See the question Michael Burr linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making it null is completely pointless, since it's about to be destroyed.

Your code isn't deleting it if it's null, due to the `if (a!=NULL)`. However, that's also pointless: applying `delete` to a null pointer will simply do nothing, so you can reduce the destructor to an unconditional `delete a;` (assuming that you know that it's either null, or points to an object created with `new`).

You do need to make sure your class either isn't copyable, or has valid copy semantics, per the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722); otherwise, copying the object will lead to deleting the same memory twice, which is not allowed.

Better still, stop juggling pointers, and use smart pointers, containers and other RAII types to make life much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call delete on a pointer that points to an object that isn't heap allocated object, ever.  If you do, the program may ignore that line.  Or it may erase your hard drive.  Or it may ignore that line on your computer, and after you give the program to a friend it erases *their* hard drive.  Don't do it.

Related: your class is missing the copy constructor, and copy assignment which are *critical* when you have a pointer that manages memory.  Alternatively, replace the `int*` member with a `unique_ptr<int>` member, which manages construction and movement for you.

Comment: ...unless the pointer is null, which is perfectly acceptable (it does nothing in that case). (Aside: downvote's not mine.)

Comment: @Cameron: Er, right. Forgot that case.