# How to stop this pointer memory-leak?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I'm decent at c++ but I've always been bad when it comes to pointers and memory. I've gotten into this situation where I don't know if there is a solution.

```
typedef unsigned long long ullong;

class MathClass { //This is just an example class
public:
    MathClass() {num = new ullong[1]();}

    MathClass operator+(MathClass b) { //This is not my actual function, just one that has the same problem
        MathClass c;
        c.num[0] = num[0] + b.num[0];
        delete [] num;
        num = NULL;
        return c;
    }
public:
    ullong* num;
};
```

This would work for a situation like this.

```
MathClass a;
MathClass b;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    a = a + b;
}
```

Because I'm setting a equal to a + b, so when the + function is run it would set a equal to c and delete the old a num.

For a situation like this it would cause an error because I'm deleting b's num.

```
MathClass a;
MathClass b;
MathClass c;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    a = b + c;
}
```

If I did not delete num this would work, but that causes memory leaks. The memory for this easily goes over 100MB when I don't delete num. I'm sure the answer to this is simple but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Unrelated: `typedef unsigned long long ullong;` always makes me want to make tea for some reason.

Comment: Any reason you are using pointers and dynamic allocation for something as trivial as an integer? This really ramps up the difficulty. The only reason you don't have a manifested [Rule of Three violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) is you leak memory.

Comment: Always prefer using smart pointers over raw `new`/`delete` - those should *almost never* be used in modern C++.

Comment: Why would you have a delete anywhere except in the destructor?

Comment: In my actual project I'm using the pointer as an array. This was just a simple class that has the same problem. In this MathClass I could have just used a regular unsigned long long, but that is not what I am using.

Answer (score 0):

You need the rule of three (five).

When you allocate memory, or if you need to implement assignment, destructor, or copy constructor, then you need all three (five - move constructor and move assignment).

When you allocate the memory with new (consider shared_ptr, unique_ptr) you require to control how copy assignment and delete work.

```
class MathClass { //This is just an example class
public:
    MathClass() {num = new ullong[1]();}
    ~MathClass() { delete [] num;} // cleans up memory.
    MathClass( const MathClass & rhs ) { num = new ullong[1](); num[0] = rhs.num[0]; }
    MathClass& operator=( const MathClass & rhs )
    {
       if( &rhs != this ) {
          num[0] = rhs.num[0];
       }
       return *this;
    }

    MathClass operator+(MathClass b) { //This is not my actual function, just one that has the same problem
    MathClass c;
    c.num[0] = num[0] + b.num[0];
    // the wrong place delete [] num;
    num = NULL;
    return c;
    }
public:
    ullong* num;
};
```

The delete [] in the operator+ was in the wrong place, as it was trying to find the correct place to free the memory.  However, the easiest way of getting it all to work is to apply the [rule of 3](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and ensure that memory was constructed at construction, deleted at deletion, and the assignment (and move) operators work correctly

Answer (score 0):

the issue actually is not exactly in the pointers but operator overloading and class implementation ( as it was mentioned in comments ). 
If you chage argumetnts order in your first example ( i.e. a = a + b -> a = b + a ) you will see the same error as in the second example. So here is good article on implementing [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) 
The code could look like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

typedef unsigned long long ullong;

class MathClass {

public:
    MathClass() { num = new ullong[ 1 ](); }
    MathClass( const MathClass &a ) { 
        *this = a;
    }
    ~MathClass() {  
        delete[] num;
        num = NULL;
    }

    MathClass &operator=( const MathClass &a ) {
        if ( this != &a ) {
            num = NULL;
            num = new ullong[ 1 ];
        }
        std::copy( a.num, a.num + 1, num );

        return *this;
    }

    friend MathClass operator+( const MathClass &a, const MathClass b ) {
        MathClass c;
        c.num[ 0 ] = a.num[ 0 ] + b.num[ 0 ];

        return c;

    }
ullong *num;
};

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
   MathClass a;
   MathClass b;
   MathClass c;
   for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i ) {
      std::cout << "a.num[ 0 ] is " << a.num[ 0 ] << std::endl;
      std::cout << "b.num[ 0 ] is " << b.num[ 0 ] << std::endl;
      a = b + a;
      a = c + b;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

In main "std::cout" used only for output visibility. There are certainly much better implementation of copy constructor then mine but the key point here is that when you are using coplex types you nearly always have to reimplement copy and assigns operator as they are very often ( if not always ) are called. 
There are some other moments that can be good to mention about your code. At least since C++11 NULL changed to `nullptr`, `typedef` is also not so common. Use reference instead of pointers and it is good practice especially in case of complex arguments to pass them by reference, not by value as in case of passing by value copy constructor will be called and you will have to instance of the same argument which can lead to memory overuse.

Comment: In the destructor after `delete[] num;`, `num` only exists for a few more  nanoseconds. There is no point to `NULL`Ing it. Rather than basing the copy constructor on `operator=`, consider basing `operator=` on the copy constructor. This allows you to take advantage of the [Copy and Swap Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) when needed.

Comment: agree about the time of existence of num in a destructor but assigning NULL to it has actually another reason. If somehow anybody have access to this memory address there will be no our values there only NULL

Comment: and thanks for the advice about "Rather than basing the copy constructor on operator=, consider basing operator= on the copy constructor. This allows you to take advantage of the Copy and Swap Idiom when needed." This is an interesting idea

Comment: I'll give you extra security as a good reason. May be worth blanking the contents of `num` before `delete`ing.

Comment: It is also recomended to set pointer to NULL after delete to avoid multiple  deleting which can lead to Undefined Behaviour, NULL pointer is a special case. Of course in this case destructor will be called once and the pointer will be deleted once.

Comment: I looked through the internet to support my words and here good disccusions to read on the topic ( if it is interesting, of course, though the topics a bit controversial and not completely support the idea exposed by me )  [Is it a good practice to NULL the pointer after deleting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931126/is-it-good-practice-to-null-a-pointer-after-deleting-it) and [Is it worth setting pointers to NULL in a destructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060006/is-it-worth-setting-pointers-to-null-in-a-destructor)

Comment: You can't delete it again. One line later in the code it no longer exists. The destructor ends and `num` goes with it. Heck, that exactly what the first answer in Is it worth setting pointers to NULL in a destructor? tells you.

Comment: Agree, that is why i wrote "Of course in this case destructor will be called once and the pointer will be deleted once. " and gave these links.

Comment: user4581301, thank you for your comments it helps me to learn new things